# How to add external PHP file to propagate in HTML landing page

Tags: php, html, mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm new to PHP and HTML and have been troubleshooting this for a few hours now, so please excuse me if I am missing something. I currently have a PHP file that calls on a MySQL table to get some rows of data. When I run the PHP file locally, the rows show up as expected so I know this is working fine. However, when I try to link this PHP file in my HTML document (because to my understanding, the .html document is what's required/is linked to my landing page/what actually shows the information), the page is completely blank and does not display the rows of information from the PHP file. Also, there is no message in my console. Is there something I am missing? Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/237/crescent-moon_1f319.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include('databasehandler.php');
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the databasehandler.php file:

```
<?php
    include_once 'includes/databasehandler.inc.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
</head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .maintext {
        margin: 0% 10%;
    }

    #text {
        z-index: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 82px;
    }
    </style>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 id="text"><center> Test Title </center></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="maintext">
        <h3><center>Welcome!</center></h3> 
        <br>
        <h5>Here is the call from the database:</h5>
    <?php
        $sql="SELECT * FROM Students;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            echo "<table border = '2'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>Student Year</th>
                </tr>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['student_id'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['student_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['student_year'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For the php code to be run, it either needs the .php extension or you need to configure it to process .html files as well.

Comment: Can we see your databasehandler.php code as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just updated the question with the code from databasehandler.php

Comment: To start, there should not be any html inside your databasehandler.php file. Remove everything but the actual php inside the php tags. So no body, style or div tags. That part is already handled by your index.html file.

Comment: Secondaly print out something like this in your index.html file to confirm you are able to run php within your index file: <?= "This is PHP"; ?>

Comment: @CodeChap if I remove all the HTML code inside the PHP file and write <?="This is pHP";?> inside the HTML file, nothing shows up. So this tells me my HTML file does not recognize PHP or maybe I'm not using the tag correctly?

Comment: Yes, your not able to process php then. You going to have to look at your setup. If your comfortable with ther terminal, you can try run php -S localhost:8080 inside your working folder and then visit http://localhost:8080 and see if you get anything that way.

Comment: @Nigel Ren is right. You have a php call in an html file, that most usually doesn't work. and is the reason you have a problem. Change the index.html file to index.php

Comment: I see. In a situation like this typically when we want to display a MySQL call on an html page, what is the best practice?